# How to change HTML class for all incoming messages in Socket.io?

Tags: html, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm trying to make a [chat app with Socket.io and Express](https://github.com/vacexpfleger/nuncioApp). Everything works fine, but this one caught me off guard. I want all incoming messages to have a different HTML class, just for styling purposes. I've already tried to do a research but nothing seems to work. I'll be grateful for any advice you can share.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please give some screenshots of your code so that it will be easy to understand the exact context of your problem

Answer (score 0):

### Add a class on creation, and remove the class prior to new messages.

In your function `outputMessage` have each new message created with a 'new' class

```js
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.classList.add("new");
```

BEFORE to injecting it into the DOM, find all `.new` elements, and remove the class

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.new').forEach(x => x.classList.remove('new'));
```

You'll likely want a system to mark clicked messages as not new as well, or some other common behavior users might expect.